# Loop running ADF Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have an ADF pipeline that needs to constantly self-restart if it completes successfully. Basically, it needs to constantly self re-run until manually stopped, BUT not be scheduled, it is a key requirement. So, interval recurrence available with triggers is not what I am looking for.

What are the simplest methods/options to accomplish it?

P.S. This ADF pipeline runs a Python script on a Databricks cluster.

Big thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

- You can use execute pipeline activity inside an until loop to achieve your requirement.
- I have a `pipeline1` and lets consider that this is your ADF pipeline that runs python script on Databricks cluster.
- Now, using a flag variable with initial value as true, use an until activity with condition as `@equals(variables('flag'),'false')`.

[image]

- Inside, I have an execute pipeline activity which runs pipeline1. Since you want to re-run the pipeline A when it runs successfully, you can use a set variable to change the flag value to `false`.

[image]

- Now as long as the pipeline1 runs successfully, it will be re-run as the until condition allows it. It stops executing when the pipeline1 fails in any case.
- You can cancel this pipeline1 manually in the monitor tab and it stops executing .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing that pops up at the top of mind is you can use a web activity at the end of the pipeline and trigger the same pipeline via REST API. This would ensure that at the end of all successful executions of all activities, you would be retriggering the pipeline.

Note : the pipeline has to be triggered manually in the 1st instance post which it would be under auto executions mode